# Function(Variable &) C++ equivalent in Ruby

Tags: ruby, methods, syntax

I'm building a function that needs to return several variables and was wondering if there is a ruby equivalent of using the C++ & in the variable declaration of the function. Such that I could do the following :

```
def function(variable &, variable2 &)
     variable = foo
     variable2 = foo
end
```

I understand that I could use the return function, but with the number of variables that I'm passing, it just doesn't look very nice in code .

Comment: Could you clarify whether you simply need to return several values at once, or do you specifically need pass-by-reference because you have some variables that you want to modify? Your C++ example effectively does both - there is no *direct* Ruby equivalent, but your needs can probably be met with Ruby in a different manner.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby does not support the concept of references to variables.

Instead, you can return multiple values by simply returning an array of the values...

```
def my_method
  return [3, 4]
end
```

... and "splatting" the results into one or more variables

```
x, y = my_method
# x => 3
# y => 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to munge pass-by-reference, the way to do this in ruby would be to define a struct-like class with accessors:

```
class MyStruct
    attr_accessor :variable, :variable2  
end

def function(mystruct)
    mystruct.variable = foo
    mystruct.variable2 = foo
end
```

You could then use metaprogramming to shorten the internals of function.  Obviously this is not as clean as a pure pass-by-reference solution but it provides a workaround.